# Failed To Send Json With NSUrlconnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

i am implementing this code wich take apple in app purchase receipt from the current transaction (not listed here) i am converting it to base64 `NSData` object, create new `NSString` with the values and keys (json object) and send it trough `NSUrlconnection` .
when the compiler hits the init with request the app crashes after 2 seconeds...
without to get any response. this is the code.

```
    NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:receiptStr];
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"receipt-data\":\"(%@)\",\"password\":\"(%@)\"}", data, SHARED_SECRET];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
savedReceipt = jsonString;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:savedReceipt forKey:@"savedrecipt"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
NSData *requestdata = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    //urlData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",requestdata]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

anyone have an idea what am i doing wrong?
i am also new to json so it could be also a problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because this line in your code:

```
[request setHTTPBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",requestdata]];
```

Is trying to setHTTPBody to some formatted NSString, when the method is actually expecting NSData.

Just use:

```
[request setHTTPBody: requestdata];
```

And see if you have better results.

Comment: great i will accept it!
do you have any idea how can i read the response?
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x27ff30>
this is what the log prints [response description]

Comment: Look at the [Apple documentation on NSHTTPURLResponse](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and you'll see how you can access the pieces of it.